# Kinect Skeletal Tracking Not Working

Tags: c#, kinect

So currently I have a `bool` `PersonDetected` which is always set to `false` **UNLESS** a Skeleton is detected. But currently when a `SkeletonTrackingState` is marked as `Tracked`, but `PersonDetected` is still set to false. Thanks in advance

#### My Code

```
Skeleton skeletons = new Skeleton();

            if ((skeletons.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked ||
                skeletons.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.PositionOnly) &
                skeletons.TrackingState != SkeletonTrackingState.NotTracked)
                {
                    PersonDetected = true;
                }
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, why are you doing x*x instead of x^2?

Comment: Why did you decide diff < 9 determines human?

Comment: Haha that was the old version, I don't know if it's still true, but even with commented out, `PersonDetected` is never `true`, and why that's there at all is because my dogs `diff` used to be under 9

Comment: @DelusionalLogic Because I'm weird like that;), actually thought I'd have to use `Math.Exponent` or whatever

Comment: @OutlawLemur depends on the compiler. from what i know Visual studio compiles the ^ operator just fine.

Comment: @DelusionalLogic It did not like ^ at all:P

Comment: @OutlawLemur good to know. i guess even the internet can be wrong sometimes. :P

Comment: Haha dont believe everything you read......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the reason that it wasn't registering was because `skeletons` was just a variable, not a `Skeleton` being tracked, so I added the following code to make sure that it worked:

```
Skeleton skeletons = new Skeleton();

            skeletons = (from s in allSkeletons
                         where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked ||
                         s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.PositionOnly
                         select s).FirstOrDefault();

            if (skeletons == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if ((skeletons.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked ||
                skeletons.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.PositionOnly))
            {
                PersonDetected = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug "diff". I'll bet it`s higher than 9

After that debug parts where you're incrementing diff.

Comment: Sorry, that was the old version, I <b>know</b> that `diff` is no longer 9, Check edit

Comment: @OutlawLemur just debug the skeleton status. Are you using KinectSkeletonChooser ?

Comment: I am using KinectSkeletonChooser

Comment: @OutlawLemur so why won`t you picked actual tracked skeleton from the skeleton chooser ? Why you create new instance of it ?